# What fuse to set to enable 16MHz clock on the atmega32u4

Tags: atmega32u4

It's my first time attempting to program an Atmega32u4, or any microcontroller for that matter, on a custom board I got printed.

avrdude has a weird output when I, for example, run this command: `sudo avrdude -c flip1 -p m32u4`. This is the output:

```
avrdude: Warning: USB bDeviceClass = 255 (expected 254)
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9587 (probably m32u4)
avrdude: Error: "lfuse" memory not accessible using FLIP
avrdude: Error: "lfuse" memory not accessible using FLIP

avrdude: Error: "lfuse" memory not accessible using FLIP
avrdude: Error: "lfuse" memory not accessible using FLIP
avrdude: Error: "lfuse" memory not accessible using FLIP
avrdude: Error: "lfuse" memory not accessible using FLIP
avrdude: safemode: Sorry, reading back fuses was unreliable. I have given up and exited programming mode

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

I'm not entirely sure why it can't read the fuse memory, but my plan is to set the fuses correctly. When I went to [this website](http://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc/) to calculate which fuses I need, I realised there's no option for a 16MHz external crystal frequency. This is an issue, I assume, because my external crystal oscillates at 16MHz.

Could this be the issue when trying to read the microcontroller's memory?

(Sorry if I got any terminology wrong, this is all very new to me)

Answer (score 1):

Code running on the 32u4 can't modify the microcontroller's own fuses -- as such, you can't write to fuses from the USB bootloader.

To modify fuses, you will need to use in-circuit programming. Hopefully you included a header for this on your board…

Comment: I didn't include an ISP header, because everything I found online about this said I could program the microcontroller from the USB port alone. Now this leads me to believe I don't need to modify any fuses, in which case I'm at a loss as to why I can't manage to program it.

Comment: How did you get the bootloader on the chip in the first place?

Comment: @alex.forencich It ships from the manufacturer with the bootloader installed.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know atmel/microchip shipped bootloaders on any AVR series parts.

Answer (score 0):

The "8MHz-" means 8 MHz or higher. Double check with the datasheet, but datasheet also has a single 8-16 MHz setting.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Unfortunately I get the same error as posted above when I attempt to run any avrdude command on the chip, so I must've done something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

According to page 30 of the datasheet, CKSEL3..1 should be 111 for 8.0 - 16.0 MHZ crystal.